# differential operator is not bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $E=\{f(x) \in L^{2}\mathbb(R)| f'(x)\in L^{2}\mathbb(R)\}$ show that differential operator is not bounded in $E$. I'm thinking in a counterexample but I can't find one. Can you find some function?

The standar norm is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\| f\|=\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{2}dx}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What is the norm of $E$? What is the codomain (with what norm)? The answer to this sort of question is heavily dependent on these sorts of things.

Comment: @tomasz I edit the question with the norm.